# CalledProcessError: Command '['pdftotext', '-layout', 'coburns.pdf', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1?

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess, pdftotext, python-re

I keep getting an error when running this portion of my code. I've tried implementing `universal_newlines=True` as suggested by the `subprocess.check_output` documentation, but I get the same error. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename in new_list:
        pdf = filename
        output = subprocess.check_output(['pdftotext', '-layout', pdf, '-'], universal_newlines=True).decode()
        pages = output.strip('\f').split('\f')
        page = pages[-1]
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-adc4a58d7f21> in <module>
      9     if filename in new_list:
     10         pdf = filename
---> 11         output = subprocess.check_output(['pdftotext', '-layout', pdf, '-'], universal_newlines=True).decode()
     12         pages = output.strip('\f').split('\f')
     13         page = pages[-1]

/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    409         kwargs['input'] = '' if kwargs.get('universal_newlines', False) else b''
    410 
--> 411     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    412                **kwargs).stdout
    413 

/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    510         retcode = process.poll()
    511         if check and retcode:
--> 512             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
    513                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    514     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['pdftotext', '-layout', 'coburns.pdf', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: [`check_ouput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is meant to raise a `CalledProcessError` if the error code from the process is not zero. Here it states that it is `1`.
You should therefore investigate why `pdftotext` yields `1` and not `0`.

Comment: pdftotext states that 1 is an indication that there was an error opening the PDF. However, if I take the pdf portion out of the for loop and conditional there is no issue. Do you think the issue is arising because of the loop itself?

Comment: You most likely trying to open something which is not a valid pdf or that does not lie where `pdftotext` looks for it. Try to print your `filename`s in the loop and check the path is correct.

Comment: `filename` prints out the correct file name. Should it be printing the entire path for the file?

Comment: It should be printing what allows `pdftotext` to find it: do you launch it from the same directory?

Comment: No, the PDF files are located in a subdirectory of the folder I'm running the code in. I would assume the for loop searching the `os.listdir(directory)` for `filename` would handle ensuring I was in the correct directory to apply the conditional based on the file name. The program needs to locate all the PDFs in a given directory if they are in `new_list' then convert it to text to look for a word conditional.

Comment: Well, at least you learned that your assumption about `os.listdir` is wrong. Your conditional is actually less about a filename (as in the name of an actual file) than a generic string (which might or not correspond to the name of an actual file). As explained in the doc of [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), you might instead want to take a look at [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), which yields objects that refer to the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is actually meant to raise a `CalledProcessError` when the code returned by the process is not `0`.

Here this code is `1`, which indicates that `pdftotext` cannot open the pdf, either because it is not correct or because it cannot find it.

You are using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), which yields filenames, that are relative to the `directory` argument, which is not necessarily the same as the current working directory in which `check_output` will launch `pdftotext` by default.

I can see three solutions:

- you can use the `cwd` argument of `check_output` to launch `pdftotext` in `directory`,
- you can reconstruct the relative path of the file either with [`os.path.join(directory, filename)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) or with [`pathlib.Path(directory)/filename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html),
- or you can replace your call of `os.listdir` with [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) which yields a [`DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) object with both `name` and `path` attributes, which you can respectively use in you test and as argument to `pdftotext`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed `pdf = filename` to `pdf = os.path.join(directory, filename)` and now it works perfectly!